# Can logstash merge several similar lines into one line?

Tags: logstash

Here is what I have in my json input from my kafka server:

```
{"deviceName":"device1", "counter":125}
{"deviceName":"device1", "counter":125}
{"deviceName":"device2", "counter":88}
{"deviceName":"device1", "counter":125}
{"deviceName":"device2", "counter":88}
{"deviceName":"device1", "counter":125}
{"deviceName":"device3", "counter":999}
{"deviceName":"device3", "counter":999}
```

I would like to get that in output:

```
{"deviceName":"device1", "counter":125, "nbOfTimes":4}
{"deviceName":"device2", "counter":88, "nbOfTimes":2}
{"deviceName":"device3", "counter":999, "nbOfTimes":2}
```

Is that possible to do that with logstash ? If yes, how is that possible ?
I saw the multine option and I don't think it can do that for me.

Thank you in adavance,

Regards,

Comment: You would use the aggregation filter for this.

Comment: The [`aggregate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) can help you achieve it, the only problem is to detect when to stop aggregating and emit the aggregated event. If your Kafka keeps receiving JSON messages, it's not easy to know when you won't receive any more messages for `device1` (e.g.) in order to output the `nbOfTimes` value.

Comment: I found this link: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-aggregate/issues/36

Comment: @Val I submitted a PR for that so you don't need a stop event. I would expect it'll be released in the next few days. So user18.. you can wait for this to be released and just use it, or you can check it out and build it locally if it is a time sensitive manner for you. Essentially you'll be using your events and set a timeout at which point they'll be pushed as a new aggregated event for you

Comment: @pandaadb, can you indicate us the reference of your PR ?

Comment: Sure thing. It just passed final code review, you can find the info here: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-aggregate/pull/37